# Combine 3 column sums into a single table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have a simple database to simulate a movie rental service. I have the following 3 select queries, which work perfectly fine on their own:

1. Calculate all revenue made from rental prices:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS RENTAL_REVENUE
       FROM RENTAL
   ```

   output:

   ```
       +----------------+
       | RENTAL_REVENUE |
       +----------------+
       |      39.92     |
       +----------------+
   ```
2. Calculate all revenue made from paid late fees:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(NULLIF(LATEFEE, 0)) AS PAID_LATE_FEES
       FROM RENTAL
       WHERE RETURNED = 1
   ```

   output:

   ```
       +----------------+
       | PAID_LATE_FEES |
       +----------------+
       |       2.99     |
       +----------------+
   ```
3. Calculate the sum of all yet unpaid late fees:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(NULLIF(LATEFEE, 0)) AS OUTSTANDING_LATE_FEES
       FROM RENTAL
       WHERE RETURNED = 0
   ```

   output:

   ```
       +-----------------------+
       | OUTSTANDING_LATE_FEES |
       +-----------------------+
       |          5.98         |
       +-----------------------+
   ```

I would like to combine the results of these 3 queries into a table with 3 columns, like so:

```
+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| RENTAL_REVENUE | PAID_LATE_FEES | OUTSTANDING_LATE_FEES |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|      39.92     |       2.99     |          5.98         |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

I was able to achieve this with the following query, but the `1 = 1` nonsense suggests to me that there might be a better way.

```
SELECT rental_revenue + paid_late_fees + outstanding_late_fees AS TOTAL_REVENUE, 
       rental_revenue, 
       paid_late_fees, 
       outstanding_late_fees 
FROM   (SELECT SUM(price) AS RENTAL_REVENUE 
        FROM   rental) 
       inner join (SELECT SUM(Nullif(latefee, 0)) AS PAID_LATE_FEES 
                   FROM   rental 
                   WHERE  returned = 1) 
               ON 1 = 1 
       inner join (SELECT SUM(Nullif(latefee, 0)) AS OUTSTANDING_LATE_FEES 
                   FROM   rental 
                   WHERE  returned = 0) 
               ON 1 = 1;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all records and build a filter inside the `SUM` using `CASE-WHEN` or `DECODE`:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS rental_revenue,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN returned = 1 AND latefee <> 0 THEN latefee
             ELSE 0
           END) AS paid_late_fees,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN returned = 0 AND latefee <> 0 THEN latefee
             ELSE 0
           END) AS outstanding_late_fees             
FROM rental
```

Comment: Why do you check that the late fee is not 0? Wouldn't it not effect the sum, anyway?

Comment: You're right but the OP checked that. I thought that if I checked it too, it would be less confusing for him.

Comment: I am OP. Lol I didn't notice that actually got in there, it's must've snuck by from some earlier tinkering I was doing :)

Comment: As an extension of the original question, how can I sum these 3 subtotals?

Comment: the `<>0` might be important if you are doing `count` instead of `sum`

Comment: and why would you need to sum the 3 together.. the `rental_revenue` is already the sum of `paid_late_fees` and `outstanding_late_fees`  (assumming there are no other values for returned)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) expression or [decode()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function

```
select sum(price) as return_revenue
     , sum(case 
             when returned = 1 
             then latefee
           end)  as paid_late_fees
     , sum(case
            when returned = 0
            then latefee
           end)  as outstanding_late_fees           
  from rental
```